# EXTJS 4.2 Google Maps API Issues

Tags: google-maps-api-3, extjs4.2

I am using V3 API for Google maps and every time I run my application in Chrome (application  works in Firefox and IE9/10)

I get an error in the console - `Cannot read property 'ROADMAP' of undefined`.

On inspection of **google.maps** object in debugger I noticed that **MapTypeId** is not defined in the object **google.maps**.  Also my fellow developers can run the same application in Chrome on their machines.

I was wondering if anybody had the same problem or can recommend a solution.